# Get ZoneId using country name, datetime and timezone offset values in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, timezone, nodatime

I have datetime(yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss), timezone offset value (K i.e -/+HH:mm) and country name and want to fetch IANA format ZoneId from these values in my web API.

Eg :

```
public static string FetchZoneID(string dateTime, string offset, string countryName)
{        
//fetch zoneID    
return zoneId;
}
```

for values

```
dateTime = "2020-02-06T06:11:01", offset = "+13:00", countryName = "New Zealand"
```

I should get

```
zoneId = "Pacific/Auckland"
```

and for values

```
dateTime = "2020-05-06T06:11:01", offset = "+12:00", countryName = "New Zealand"
```

I should get (due to DST)

```
zoneId = "Pacific/Auckland"
```

Currently using NodaTime, I was able to fetch all zoneIds for a particular country, but unable to figure out on how to filter these based on datetime and offset values.

```
var zoneIds = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.Where(x => x.CountryName == countryName)
    .Select(x => x.ZoneId);
```

Can someone help me on this?

Note: In case of multiple zoneIds being eligible for the given offset, the first value would be used.

Comment: Why?  There could be 10 cities with the same offset so why do you think you should get Brisbane?

Comment: I don't mind getting multiple zoneId's for the given input

Comment: My point was it is not unique.  The ZoneLocation value is not built into the Net Library and the application has to set the parameter.

Comment: Updated my example to avoid confusion

Comment: Note that `America/Detroit` and `America/New_York` almost always have the same offset, but are two different timezones in the same country. Which one do you want to get? Another example is `Asia/Shanghai` and `Asia/Hong_Kong`.

Comment: @Sweeper for such scenarios we have the flexibility to choose any of them. FirstOrDefault() would be used

Comment: You may think choosing first/any would be sufficient, but it is not. There are many examples where two *very* different time zones could have the same offset at some particular date and time, even in the same country. Even in the US. I will add an answer with an example later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll change your method signature slightly, and show how you can a list of *all* possible time zone ids for a given country where the offset matches for a particular local date and time:

```cs
public static ICollection<string> FetchZoneIds(OffsetDateTime dateTime, string countryCode)
{
    return TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
        .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
        .Select(x => dateTime.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[x.ZoneId]))
        .Where(x => x.Offset == dateTime.Offset)
        .Select(x => x.Zone.Id)
        .ToList();
}
```

Here's a little test method to illustrate calling with string inputs and dump to the output:

```cs
private static void Test(string dtoString, string countryCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{dtoString} ({countryCode})");

    var offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTimePattern.GeneralIso.Parse(dtoString).Value;
    var zoneIds = FetchZoneIds(offsetDateTime, countryCode);

    foreach (var zoneId in zoneIds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(zoneId);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Your first examples gives the single expected result:

```cs
Test("2020-02-06T06:11:01+13:00", "NZ");
```

```
2020-02-06T06:11:01+13:00 (NZ)
Pacific/Auckland
```

So does your second example:

```cs
Test("2020-05-06T06:11:01+12:00", "NZ");
```

```
2020-05-06T06:11:01+12:00 (NZ)
Pacific/Auckland
```

But look what happens here:

```cs
Test("2020-11-01T01:00:00-05:00", "US");
```

```
2020-11-01T01:00:00-05:00 (US)
America/New_York
America/Detroit
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/Kentucky/Monticello
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Vincennes
America/Indiana/Winamac
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Petersburg
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Chicago
America/Indiana/Tell_City
America/Indiana/Knox
America/Menominee
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
America/North_Dakota/Beulah
```

Importantly, note that there are entries for *both* Eastern Time and Central Time in the results, the main ones being `America/New_York` and `America/Chicago`.  How can that be?

No, it's not a bug.  [You can verify it here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20201101T060000&p1=64&p2=179).  In the US, daylight saving time doesn't happen all at once.  It goes one time zone at a time from the east to the west.  So when the fall-back transition takes place in the Eastern time zone (2:00 EDT becoming 1:00 EST), the Central time zone is still at 1:00 EDT.  It doesn't transition for another hour.  In other words, it's 1:00 with a UTC-5 offset in both EST and CDT *at the same time*.

If you don't care about such things, sure you could just do a `.FirstOrDefault()` (the default being a `null` string when there is no match).  But you may indeed encounter edge cases like this one.

Comment: I understand your concern regarding the edge cases, that's a documented limitation we have for our application and fine to be with.